# Property documents required for a UK visit visa from Pakistan

Tags: paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

hi just wondering if anyone knows what property documents are required to be submitted to prove proof of ownership of real estate in pakistan for a visit visa to the uk? is a purchase agreement good enough?

Comment: You ask for an interpretation of a document whose text you do not reveal. However, under common law a "purchase agreement" is _ipso facto_ an agreement to buy, and can establish only that one has agreed to purchase the property. Such a document does not, therefore, prove present ownership.

Comment: The title deeds showing eg the full name of the owner(s) and the address of the property would be typical. A purchase agreement doesn’t sound like it would be sufficient